# Python: Append a dictionary as a new object to a dictionary key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am developing a Django API to populate certain sets of data under different sections/categories. In there each section/catergory will have multiple dictionaries.

Requirement:

```
"data": {
    "engineers": {
        {"id": 1, "name": "aaa"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "bbb"},
        {"id": 3, "name": "ccc"},
    },
    "doctors": {
        {"id": 5, "age": "50"},
        {"id": 6, "age": "60"},
        {"id": 7, "age": "70"},
    },
}
```

In this example I need to append new engineer objects to "engineers" node, and new doctor objects to "doctors" node. The method I've tried is as follows.

```
data = {}
data["engineers"].append({"id": 4, "name": "ddd"})
data["doctors"].append({"id": 8, "age": "45"})
```

Error:

> During handling of the above exception ('set' object is not
>   subscriptable), another exception occurred:

How can I do this?

Comment: You are appending to a dict object and that wont work, so engineers must be a list object not a dict, the first time you define it to it with [] and not {}, same with doctors

Comment: The requirement is not valid Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending to a dict object and that wont work, so engineers must be a list object not a dict, the first time you define it to it with [] and not {}, same with doctors.

```
data = {
'engineers':[],
'doctors':[]
} 
data["engineers"].append({"id": 4, "name": "ddd"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your data that you want to append to in an array. You can't append to a dictionary, but you can append objects to an array.

```py
data = {"Engineers":
    [
        {"id": 1, "name": "Bob"}
    ]
}

data["Engineers"].append({
    "id": 2, "name": "Alice"
})
```

This will produce:

```
{"Engineers": 
  [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Bob"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Alice"}
  ]
}
```